# How could I get shader kind (vertex/pixel, etc.) from ID3D11ShaderReflection?

Tags: shader, direct3d, direct3d11

I want to extract shader program type informantion from shader byte code. I tried `D3D11Reflect` first, and I found the `_D3D11_SHADER_DESC` structure. But I couldn't identify which field stores program type information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `d3d11shader.h` header, you'll see it's encoded into the Version field in the 16-bit upper word:

```
typedef enum D3D11_SHADER_VERSION_TYPE
{
    D3D11_SHVER_PIXEL_SHADER    = 0,
    D3D11_SHVER_VERTEX_SHADER   = 1,
    D3D11_SHVER_GEOMETRY_SHADER = 2,

    // D3D11 Shaders
    D3D11_SHVER_HULL_SHADER     = 3,
    D3D11_SHVER_DOMAIN_SHADER   = 4,
    D3D11_SHVER_COMPUTE_SHADER  = 5,

    D3D11_SHVER_RESERVED0       = 0xFFF0,
} D3D11_SHADER_VERSION_TYPE;

#define D3D11_SHVER_GET_TYPE(_Version) \
(((_Version) >> 16) & 0xffff)
#define D3D11_SHVER_GET_MAJOR(_Version) \
(((_Version) >> 4) & 0xf)
#define D3D11_SHVER_GET_MINOR(_Version) \
(((_Version) >> 0) & 0xf)

typedef struct _D3D11_SHADER_DESC
{
    UINT    Version;  // Shader version
    ...
}  D3D11_SIGNATURE_PARAMETER_DESC;
```